# WebDAV on IIS 7.5 with SSL (self signed) - Windows can't connect - Mac can only mount it readonly

Tags: macos, iis, ssl, webdav

Today I spent the whole day investigating why I have so many problems with WebDAV.

My Server is running Windows 2008 R2 with IIS7.5.
I created a self signed certificate and added it to the "Default Web Site". I enabled Windows Authentication and installed the WebDAV Extension.

I enabled Locking WebDAV Settings as you see here:
http://www.abload.de/img/webdavydkea.png

I then created a folder called Shares on C:\ and changed added writting permissions for the domain users.

At the end I created the Virtual Directory and set the "Authorization Rules" and the "WebDav Authorization Rules".

At the end I force the usage of SSL with the previously self signed certificate.

Now I try to connect with MAC OS X 10.7 and MAC OS X 10.6 and both mount it readonly.

If I try to mount it in Windows I get the following error message:

The mapped network drive could not be created because the following error has occurred:
A device attached to the system is not functioning.

More details if I try to mount it by using the command line:
System error 1244 has occurred.
The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated.

If I now disable the SSL support I can mount it in Windows too including write support. MAC OS X still does only mount it as read only.

Altogether I have the following problems:

- Why does MAC OS X mount the WebDAV directory as readonly even so I enabled locking support?
- Why does Windows not work if I try to use SSL with the self signed certificate?

Comment: One step further: Mac OS X does now mount it including write support IF I disable SSL.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup, and just experienced the same "cannot connect from Windows 7" problem.

I found that I can connect from a Win XP machine. On connecting, a popup asks me if I want to trust the self-signed cert -> I accept -> it connects well.

This made me suspect that the Win 7 problem is with the cert (with not showing a popup to let me manually accept the self-signed cert). The solution to make it work is:

- Either import the self-signed cert in Win 7 / IE9 into the "Trusted root CA"
  cert store.
- Or buy a cert that is signed by a known cert authority.